what is the metrics I can use to monitor eventbridge invocation limits?
I deployed a EventBus to AWS EventBridge with a few rules. According to EventBridge limits https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-quota.html, there is one limit Invocations throttle limit in transactions per second which is different for different regions.
My question is that which metric I can use to monitor the usage? Is the metric on EventBus level or on rule level? I have checked a few metrics, Invocations, TriggeredRule but their value is not really the actual usage of the event bridge. What is the right metric I should look at?

You can monitor metric ThrottledRules: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-monitoring.html

with "usage" you mean the number of events sent to EventBridge? If so, these should help PutEventsApproximate* https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-monitoring.html#eb-metrics
